# Is this formula true? $a + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^n = \frac{y}{y-x}a$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, solution-verification

I was thinking about Supertasks (see [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supertask)), and wanted to be able to find the total amount of time the Supertask takes using an equation.

This is what I came up with:

$$a + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^na = \frac{y}{y-x}a$$

Is this true? If not, is it true when $x = 1$ and $y = 2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $|x|<|y|$, then $|x/y|<1$ and we can use the usual geometric series formula
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n = \frac1{1-r}, \quad \text{provided } |r|<1.$$
This means that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n = \frac r{1-r}.$$
Substitute $r=x/y$ and you *almost* get your formula, but there's a slight error. Note that
$$\frac r{1-r} = \frac{\frac xy}{1-\frac xy} = \frac x{y-x}.$$

When $|x|\ge |y|$, the sum does not converge.

Comment: Thanks, I'm fairly new to this type of math so I didn't think about the fact that if y > x then of course It would increase infinitely

Comment: Well, when $|y|\ge |x|$, the size of the terms does not go to $0$. If one number if negative, you will get alternating positive/negative terms. Still plenty of math for you to learn :P

Comment: Most of this math I do as a hobby, I'm really only fluent in grade 10 level math, and everything past that is fragmented :) (also, I did consider that with negative values involved interesting stuff would happen, but I wasn't sure)